# Why is it going in the wrong direction?

Tags: transforms, pose-mode

Every time I move the Y location the hat follows the green line instead of following the y-axis. It still follows the axis in object mode. I've been trying to change the transformation orientation and the XYZ rotation in the item transform menu, but I can't find the problem.
[image]

Comment: hello, please share the object with the problem: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It's too hard to tell from that one image.  I would need to see the f-curve editor expanded to show the x,y, and z locations of the object, plus some other data.  Can you share your blend file? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)